# Allow switch to toggle only if internet connection is available

Tags: java, android, android-switch

I have used a switch in my android code.
If internet service is available then only allow toggle else show a toast message. How do I achieve this?
I am unable to do so using

`switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener()`.

The check is working only if I press the switch button twice.

```
aSwitch.setEnabled(false);
```

works only after I click once

Comment: when the toast will be shown according to your requirement ?

Comment: If there is a internet connection, toggle switch and if there is no internet then it will show a toast message and the toggle switch should not work.

Answer (score 4):

First create a boolean that carries a flag :

```
boolean checkInternetFlag = false;
```

Then create a method that check if internet is available like this for example:

```
public final boolean isInternetOn() {
  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
  return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

You will also need to add this permission in your manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Then you can do what you want in a condition like this :

```
        checkInternetFlag = isInternetOn();
    if (!checkInternetFlag) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Internet not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Also you can disable your toggle switch like this :

```
aSwitch.setEnabled(false);
```

And to make switch not clickable use :

```
aSwitch.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Yes I have done the check but the toggle switch is still active

Answer (score 0):

The following method will catch if there is a change occured to networkstate:

**1)Add this code to onCreate():**

```
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
  NetworkChangeReceiver receiver = new NetworkChangeReceiver();
  registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

**2) Add OnDestroy() Method:**

```
 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  Log.v(LOG_TAG, "onDestory");
  super.onDestroy();

  unregisterReceiver(receiver);

 }
```

**3) Add the Following Code to your activity:**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent)
    {

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Receieved notification about network status");
        isNetworkAvailable(context);

    }


    private boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)
                                           context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                {
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        if(!isConnected)
                        {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Now you are connected to Internet!");
                            aSwitch.setEnabled(true);
                            isConnected = true;
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Internet is not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        aSwitch.setEnabled(false);
        isConnected = false;
        return false;
        }
    }
```

**4)Add this permission in your manifest file :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hopefully this relates to your requirement.

Comment: If I use   **aSwitch.setEnabled(false);**, when internet connection is restored it does not work since I am using this code inside my adapter of navigation drawer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you have to use BroadcastReceiver to listen the network state change and then trigger your code.

Comment: I've edited my answer, if not solved you may have a look at this answer.